# how to make the transform.up of a gameobject be colliear with a vector, without changing it's Y rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

So... I'll try to be as clear as possible, if I let something unclear please let me know.

I have a vector that comes from origin and go to a point in space, and I have an object that I want it's transform.up (Or Y vector) to be colinear with this vector, but the Y rotation of this object is driven by another factor, and I dont want to change it.

So far, what I'm trying to do is project this vector in the local XY and local ZY planes and measure the angles and apply rotation:

```
float xInclination = Mathf.Atan(Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(orbitMomemtumVector, transform.right).z / Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(orbitMomemtumVector, transform.right).y)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
float yInclination = Mathf.Atan(initialPos.z / initialPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
float zInclination = -Mathf.Atan(Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(orbitMomemtumVector, transform.forward).x / Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(orbitMomemtumVector, transform.forward).y)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;

if (initialPos.x < 0 && initialPos.z > 0)
{
    yInclination = 180f - Mathf.Abs(yInclination);
    argumentPeriapsis = argumentPeriapsis - yInclination;
}
else if (initialPos.x < 0 && initialPos.z < 0)
{
    yInclination = 180f + Mathf.Abs(yInclination);
    argumentPeriapsis = argumentPeriapsis - yInclination;
}
else
{
    argumentPeriapsis = argumentPeriapsis - yInclination;
}

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xInclination, (float)argumentPeriapsis, zInclination);
```

This image shows the problem, I need the Y arrow to be collinear with the blue line

[image]

Comment: How do you want to change its orientation ... without changing its orientation?

Comment: It's not working, the Y vector sometimes is indeed collinear, but depending on the location of orbitMomemtumVector the rotation is completely wrong

Comment: does something speak against using `transform.up = directionVector;`?

Comment: I added an image to help visualize the problem, I tried to set transform.up = directionVector, but when I do it, the Y rotation also changes, and I need the gameObject to be offset by argumentPeriapsis in the Y rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me be clear on this, don't use Euler angles in 3d space. In fact, avoid them in 2d games as well. Unless your object truly rotates on a single axis, and you never have to get the angle between two rotations, or lerp your rotations, don't use them.

What you want is `Quaternion.LookRotation(A, B)`.

`A` being a vector to which `Z` will be colinear, `X` being orthogonal to the plane defined by `A` and `B`, and `Y` belonging to that plane.

Followup:

To match other axis to A, there are multiple solutions. First would be to simply apply the lookRotation to a parent object, while the child object is rotated inside to match whatever rotation you want. You can also edit your entire mesh to do so.

The other way is to simply apply another rotation, so that both combined get your desired result, like so:

```
Quaternion zMatched = Quaternion.LookRotation(zAxisTarget, direction)
Quaternion yMatched = zMatched * Quaternion.AngleAxis(90f, Vector3.right);
transform.rotation = yMatched;
```

This will rotate the object so that the y axis becomes collinear to the previous z axis.

This is however nor perfect. If you reach this point, you should consider building your own clearer solution based on combining AngleAxis results. But it works well enough.

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work, as shown in the picture, I need that the Y axis is collinear with the blue line, not the Z axis

Comment: Thank you, this solution was very enlightening, not yet the perfect result but is definitely the path.

Comment: I didn't test the code, so if you get a good result (i think switching the order of the quaternion multiplication might help), please share.